# Recursively converting a base ten number to base two

Tags: c, recursion

For a homework assignment, I've been asked to create a recursive function that takes an int and an int pointer and prints a binary representation of the first int and leaves the pointer's destination with the number of ones in the binary.

It works for some values - 65 and 99 work - but not for most others (negatives are outside the problem domain). I don't know why.

```
void binaryPrinter(int value, int *numberOfOnes)
{
    int thisbit;

    //printf("Value is %i",value);

    if (value <= 0) { 
        printf("%i",value);
        return;
    } else if (value == 1){
        printf("1");
        *numberOfOnes = *numberOfOnes + 1;
        return;
    }


    thisbit = value % 2;
    if (thisbit) { *numberOfOnes = *numberOfOnes + 1; }
    printf("%i",thisbit);
    binaryPrinter(value / 2, numberOfOnes);
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're printing the least-significant bits first, i.e. you're printing the numbers in reverse.

65 and 99 are binary palindromes, so the results are fine.

Print the current bit's result *after* calling (and printing) the higher-order bits.

```
// rest of the function as before, but at the very end...

binaryPrinter(value / 2, numberOfOnes);
printf("%i",thisbit);
```

Comment: 'S always the little things that get ya, especially when you're coding while tired. :P